# { match } in React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm looking through the examples and I see this Router configured.

```
  <Router>
  ....
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
    ....
```

Why is it that Topics has "`{ match }`" for the function parameter?  Why doesn't it use "props" and then in the function definition props.match?

Comment: See [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: `{match}` is equivalent to `props.match` in the particular example you linked.